# Rails File.open(#{Rails.root}) is vulnerable to LFI?

Tags: audit, ruby, rails, file-inclusion

I am performing White Box testing on Rails application with static code analyzing tools like brakeman, I came across an instance where the developer is loading images using file.open.

```
file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/path/image.jpg")
```

Due to my limited knowledge in rails, I am wondering if that's vulnerable to LFI Issue or not. According to my knowledge if we use `File.open([:path])` user-defined parameter then it will be vulnerable to LFI. But have confusion in case of rails.root.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails.root` appears to return the root directory of the Rails app. As this is not user controlled input, it is not/cannot be used for LFI of any sort.

Comment: Which concludes to that brakeman just reporting because of File.open has been used, considering a false positive then. Anyways, thank you!!!